# Correct way to apply margin attributes (particularly, in Bootstrap)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

My limited CSS knowledge is starting to catch up with me now and I'm not sure how to handle this particular situation, despite grappling over it in various forms for months.

So I was having this problem awhile back with my  solid-color Bootstrap navbar where it didn't fully extend to the right side of the browser by a handful of pixels. I could never figure out why but I did figure out a while back that overriding .row with a margin-right attribute of 0, fixed this problem. Fast forward a few weeks, I just noticed that my grey content boxes are now off-centered, as in, the margins between the left side and content and the right side and content were not the same, clearly because of this change I had previously made.

Now I can offset this problem by overriding .row with a margin-left attribute of 0 (and then messing with padding in comparison to those values to get the desired effect) but I'm really just not sure if this is bad practice or not? As .row is one of the most used classes of all in Bootstrap, I feel like I'm hacking away when there must be a elegant solution (where one problem I can't figure out is how to apply the margin-right styling to certain outer rows and not in certain rows - which would be a nightmare to try and figure out where at this stage of my project). I did try  for a little while to apply this margin-right: 0 attribute just to the specific rows I thought were the culprit for the navbar issue but in the end, I wasn't able to figure it out.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: can you post a JSFiddle so we can reproduce your issue?

Comment: You are hacking apart Bootstrap. Please spend some time familiarizing yourself with how the [Bootstrap Grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) works. You really shouldn't need to mess with `.row`, if you need to then it's likely you're misusing the Bootstrap Grid classes. The margins on `.row` are there to "pull out" the padding applied by the column classes - so everything lines up nicely.

Comment: I feel like that'd be way too complex to reproduce, I don't think it'd be too helpful as I would probably leave out important pieces. Somewhere, it develops this problem, and I'm not sure where. I wasn't the only one who had the problem about the navbar fully extending to the side, I actually found the 'solution' to that on another Stack question (I just can't seem to find those questions right now). What I'm mainly trying to ask in this question is how bad a practice is it to override all of .row with margin-left/right attributes of 0.

Comment: @chelseanderby it's a bad practice that most developers won't tell you it's okay off-hand. Kind of like you shouldn't use `!important` unless you know what you're doing. If you can't list a handful of genuine pros and cons of using `!important` for a particular situation other than _"it works"_ then you're likely not experienced enough to use `!important` intelligently/properly. Same with `.row` of Bootstrap. If you don't know the pros and cons (implications) then it's likely that it's not good. And in you're case it sounds like _"you're doing it wrong."_

Comment: @chelseanderby Without code and a solid example you're unlikely to get solid answers.Replicating the issue with code in your post is advisable and worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

you should not change the css properties of a Bootstrap class, for many reasons: above all

1. you could create regression somewhere else in your site (as already happened to you)
2. you can't be sure what will happen to your site if you upgrade the bootstrap css to a new release

You should

1. add a specific ID or a specific custom class to the originary navbar that had that issue
2. then create a custom css file (that you will import in you web pages after importing all bootstrap css files)
3. add in this new custom css file a rule to the previous new ID/class for the navbar that fix the original problem

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be nesting a container within a container, or a similar nesting issue. I cannot tell without a code sample.

You shouldn't need to use a row on your navbar, bootstrap has its own classes for a navbar.

See http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp for some snippets on how to do this.

Also you should never edit the bootstrap file, create an override file and put any changes you make into there. Make sure you link to the override file after the bootstrap file so that it cascades correctly. Like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-override.css">
```